# Assigning a color to a DataGridView Row

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to make this Windows Application, where you can register Gym Members and their Monthly Payments. I have this DataGridView where it displays some properties of the member, and one of them is the field STATUS. This field contains the word PAID or UNPAID (which is assigned from some code, if the member payed or not). Now what I want to do is : If the Status field is UNPAID, I want that row to be RED (background color). Is that possible ? If yes how can I do that ?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067068/conditional-datagridview-formatting

Comment: please check this link think this well help u 


[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189376/c-sharp-how-to-change-row-color-in-datagridview][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189376/c-sharp-how-to-change-row-color-in-datagridview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a `DataGridView` called `dgv`. Try something like the following

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
{
    if (row.Cells["STATUS"].Value != null &&
        row.Cells["STATUS"].Value.ToString().CompareTo("UNPAID") == 0)
    {
        row.Cells["STATUS"].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
    else
    {
        row.Cells["STATUS"].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
    }
}
```

This will colour your 'UNPAID' cells red and the others green. This assumes you only have to available values.

I hope this helps.

*Edit. To colour the entire row you can use `row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red` etc.*

Comment: I actually wanted the whole row to be in red, but this looks better !
Thank you :) Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I think you must to loop through the rows in the grid-view and then compare values:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in grid.Rows) 
     if (row.Cells["STATUS"].Value =="UNPAID") 
     {
         row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red; 
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

what you could do is set the color of the cells in the row to red like this:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    if (row.Cells["STATUS"].Value =="UNPAID") 
        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

Wich would set the row of cells where the value of Status is unpaid to red.