# Fill DataGridView row according to a string value of a cell

Tags: c#, datagridview, colors

Im trying to fill a row according to a string text, better explained:

Cell number 7 has 2 values ("1 - Pago" or "2- Pendente"), if its the 1 option i want that row painted in Green, else i want it red.

I tried several codes, but i cant get it, i have this so far:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DataGridView1.Rows) 
 if (Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[7].Value) == "1- Pago)) 
 {
     row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red; 
 }
```

Pretty sure, error is on 2 line, but im new and i still couldnt find a solution, i  tried changed Value to Text, still errors.

Thank you.

Comment: You have forgot to close the double quotes in if statement

Comment: This code won`t compile. EVER.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 major compile errors:

1) You tried to equal Int and String

2) Your string at right side of equation doesnt have proper "" symbol at the end.

Try this:

```
 foreach (DataGridViewRow row in vendorsDataGridView.Rows) 
      if (row.Cells[7].Value.ToString() == "1 - Pago") 
           row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

Comment: Thank you, the code does now compile, but it crashes when i run it: An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in WindowsFormsApplication2.exe

Comment: @DuarteAndrade you have to debug and find out which particular variable is null

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to convert a text into a Integer number. Try changing the second row to

```
if (row.Cells[7].Value.ToString() == "1 - Pago")
```

Also, pay attention to spaces inside your string, if you miss one while writing the option, this will not work.

Comment: Your code also won't compile. You are trying to apply `==` to `int` and `string`. And you have one extra`)`

Comment: Thanks for the comment you were totally right, just fixed it.

Comment: Thank you, the code does now compile, but it crashes when i run it: An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in WindowsFormsApplication2.exe

Comment: Would you please check if row.Cells[7] has any value? Are you sure this is the index for your information?

Comment: Well, it was index 8, but still gives me same error.

Comment: Can you tell me where that code should be ? i have it in a button, so i press it when i want the row colored.

Comment: Well it depends on what you want to trigger it, usually people use the code on the datagrid cell formating event such as in the following [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067068/conditional-datagridview-formatting).

Comment: Try `if (row.Cells[7].Value != null && row.Cells[7].Value.ToString() == "1 - Pago")`.  If this doesn't fix it, then your `NullReferenceException` is referring to another line of code and as @Szer stated, you'll have to debug that one.

Comment: Thanks for your time, No errors now, but cells dont change color.

Comment: its working ! Thanks so much to all :) Also, its possible to use costum colors, i feel these red and green too agressive.