# switch color in c# linked to database

Tags: c#, datagridview, colors

I am working on a C# software linked to database with a datagridview. i want to switch the color of the last cell in every row. when the number is greater then 5 --> green if 5-->yellow and less then 5--> red. any help ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4067612/1271037

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code showing what you've tried so far.

Comment: at which point in time do you wish this change to be executed?

Comment: in my code in can edit on the datagridview and update the database. so the number will be updated. and i want the colors to switch related to the number inside the cells

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
public void Color()
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in ProductServicesDataGrid.Rows)
            if (Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[5].Value) > Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[6].Value))
            {
                row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.DarkGreen;
            }
            else if (Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[5].Value) < Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[6].Value))
            {
                row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Yellow;
            }
            else if (Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[5].Value) == 0 && Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[6].Value) > Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[5].Value))
            {
                row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            }
            else
            {
                row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.DarkBlue;
            }
    }
```