# i have change the background color of row in datagridview if already expired the medicine?

Tags: vb.net

i have change the background color of row in datagridview if already expired the medicine?

```
        con.Open()
        Dim query As String
        query = "Select product_code,drug_name,quantity,expiration_date from medicine where expiration_date"
        command = New MySqlCommand(query, con)
        readers = command.ExecuteReader

        Dim count As Integer
        count = 0
        While readers.Read
            count = count + 1
        End While
        con.Close()
        If count = 0 Then
            MsgBox("no expiration")
        Else
            Dim SQL As String = ""
            Dim da As MySqlDataAdapter = Nothing
            Dim dt As New DataTable
            SQL = "Select product_code,drug_name,quantity,expiration_date from medicine where expiration_date"
            command = New MySqlCommand(SQL, con)
        End If
```

Comment: See the [DataGridView.CellFormatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting) event. Or [DataGridView.RowValidating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowvalidating). Or [DataGridView.RowPrePaint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowprepaint). The method you choose depends on different factors; for example, when this style should be applied.

Comment: Also, see [DataGridViewRow.DefaultCellStyle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.defaultcellstyle) and its `BackColor` property.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditional DataGridView Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067068/conditional-datagridview-formatting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok fist of all you need to load de grid with the database data in this way:

```
    con.Open()
        Dim query As String
        Dim da As new MySqlDataAdapter
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        query = "Select product_code,drug_name,quantity,expiration_date from medicine where expiration_date is not null"
        command = New MySqlCommand(query, con)
        da.SelectCommand = cm
        da.Fill(dt)
        dgv1.datasource = dt
```

Then you have to set the color in the cellformating event:

```
 Private Sub dgv1_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles dgv1.CellFormatting
        If dgv1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("expiration_date").Value < now Then
            dgv1.Rows(e.RowIndex).cells("expiration_date").Style.BackColor = Color.Red
        End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand what you are trying to do or how you are going to load the grid. any way to change the color of a column all you have to do is:

```
           dgv1.Columns("columnsName").DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red
```

Comment: i have a medicine to expired in database and then change the color of rows to identified the medicine if expired.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm saying it by from memory
try this.

dgv1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("expiration_date").Style.BackColor = Color.Red